# Call an azure function and set a variable in logic app

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

Is there a way (or an example) of calling an azure function and it returning and setting a variable in logic app ?

Comment: you mean you want to put the body response in a variable ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can call HTTP-triggered Functions from your Logic App and then continue to work with the response. There's even a nice tutorial from the Microsoft Docs team showing how you can combine Logic Apps & Azure Functions:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-twitter-email